# Extracting part of string based on two conditions

Tags: r, text, mining

I have a character column in my data set from which I want to extract part of a string based on two conditions:

a) if the string starts with "Therapist:", split the string to two columns: one column with the word "Therapist" and the other column with the remaining text.

b) if it is a "Patient:", split the string to two columns: one column with the word "Patient" and the other column with the remaining text.

The problem that I have been having is that I don't know how to create if statements in R. I'm a newbie but very willing to learn. Even after googling (stackoverflow, etc.) and trying different functions, I'm still at a loss.

Example of the data I have:

> data$speech[1:5]

[1] "Therapist: Okay, we’re back…"

[2] "Patient: Hmm-hmm."

[3] "Therapist: … after a couple of hours…"

[4] "Patient: Hmm-hmm."

[5] "Therapist: Hmm… Catch me up on what you’ve found yourself thinking and feeling after the session."

I really appreciate it.

Thank you!

​

Comment: What is the expected output for the example?

Comment: @SvenHohenstein two columns: one with either “Therapist” or “Patient”, the other column with the remaining string of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command creates a two-columns data frame:

```
as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(data$speech, ": ")))
```

The result:

```
         V1                                                                                     V2
1 Therapist                                                                      Okay, we’re back…
2   Patient                                                                               Hmm-hmm.
3 Therapist                                                             … after a couple of hours…
4   Patient                                                                               Hmm-hmm.
5 Therapist Hmm… Catch me up on what you’ve found yourself thinking and feeling after the session.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `separate()` form the `{tidyr}` package.

```
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(
  speech = c(
    "Therapist: Okay, we’re back…",
    "Patient: Hmm-hmm.",
    "Therapist: … after a : couple of hours…",
    "Patient: Hmm-hmm.",
    "Therapist: Hmm… Catch me up on what you’ve : found yourself thinking and feeling after the session."
  )
)

separate(df, speech, into = c("Name", "Talk"), sep = ":", extra = "merge")

       Name                                                                                      Talk
1 Therapist                                                                         Okay, we’re back…
2   Patient                                                                                  Hmm-hmm.
3 Therapist                                                              … after a : couple of hours…
4   Patient                                                                                  Hmm-hmm.
5 Therapist  Hmm… Catch me up on what you’ve : found yourself thinking and feeling after the session.
```

I use the argument `extra = "merge"` to deal with the presence of `:` in the speech.